# How to detect if string "_numbers" here

Tags: python

I need to detect, if string contains "_numbers", e.g.:

> "4MYLUV3_27113.jpg" - true , "5cr00g3.jpg" - false , 
>   "*Joshua969*.jpg"- false ,  "20comer100saber_lol.jpg" - false

The Number may have from 1 to 6 digits.
Thanks for any answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `re.search`

```
if re.search(r'_\d{1,6}\b', s):
```